# recursion within a class

Tags: python

I am trying to place a recursive formula inside a class statement

```
class SomeNode:

    def __init__(self, a):
        leng = len(a)
        half= leng/2
        self.firstnode=a[0][0]
        self.child1=SomeNode([a[i]for k in range(leng)])
        self.child2=SomeNode([a[j] for j in range(leng)])


    def recursfunc(self):
        print self.firstnode
        recursfunc(self.child1)
        recursfunc(self.child2)
```

However I keep getting the error message NameError: global name 'recursfunc' is not defined

Comment: Your constructor has an inifinite recursion.  And `[a[j] for j in range(leng)]` with `leng = len(a)` can be abbreviated by `a`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `self.recursfunc()`

Comment: Or better `self.child1.recursfunc()`.

Comment: its better to use @classmethods for recurive functions ( or static methods...)

Answer (score 0):

```
def tri_recursion(k):
  if(k>0):
    result = k+tri_recursion(k-1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use : SomeNode.recursfunc(self.child1) or self.child1.recursfunc().

I believe they have no difference, but I will like if someone can give a in-depth explanation for this.