# Function to Calculate the height of a Binary Search Tree is not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search-tree

I have tried various methods in order to calculate the height of a Binary Search Tree which includes recursion and also using a list in order to add the node along with it's depth.But for both the methods,the output is not correct.

Here's my code for the same:

```
class Node:
def __init__(self,data):
    self.data=data
    self.left=None
    self.right=None

def Insert_BTreeNode(self,data):
    if self.data:
        if data<=self.data:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left=Node(data)
            else:
                self.left.Insert_BTreeNode(data)

        elif data>self.data:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right=Node(data)

            else:
                self.right.Insert_BTreeNode(data)

    else:
        self.data=data

def Lookup(self,data,parent=None):

    if data<self.data:
        if self.left is None:
            return None,None
        return self.left.Lookup(data,self)
    elif data>self.data:
        if self.right is None:
            return None,None
        return self.right.Lookup(data,self)
    else:
        if (parent is not None):
            print(self.data,parent.data)
        return (self,parent)

def Children_count(self):
    count=0

    if self.left:
        count+=1
    if self.right:
        count+=1

    return (count)

def Delete(self,data):
    children_count=0
    node,parent=self.Lookup(data)
    if node is not None:
        children_count=node.Children_count()

    if children_count==0:
        if parent:
            if parent.left is Node:
                parent.left=None
            else:
                parent.right=None
            del node
        else:
            self.data=data

    elif children_count==1:
        if node.left:
            n=node.left
        else:
            n=node.right
        if parent:
            if parent.left is node:
                parent.left=n
            else:
                parent.right=n
            del node
        else:
            self.left=n.left
            self.right=n.right
            self.data=n.data

    else:
        parent=node
        successor=node.right

        while successor.left:
            parent=successor
            successor=successor.left
        node.data=successor.data

        if parent.left==successor:
            parent.left=successor.right

        else:
            parent.right=successor.right

def print_treeInorder(self):
    if self.left:
        self.left.print_treeInorder()
    print(self.data)
    if self.right:
        self.right.print_treeInorder()


def print_treePostorder(self):
    if self.left:
        self.left.print_treePostorder()
    if self.right:
        self.right.print_treePostorder()
    print(self.data)

def height(self):
    if self is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return max(height(self.getLeft()), height(self.getRight()))+ 1

def print_treePreorder(self):
    print(self.data)

    if self.left:
        self.left.print_treePreorder()
    if self.right:
        self.right.print_treePreorder()

def getLeft(self):
    return self.left

def getRight(self):
    return self.right

def maxDepth(self): #Level order Traversal
    if self is None:
        return 1
    q=[]
    q.append([self,1])
    while(len(q))!=0:
        node,temp=q.pop()
        if node.getLeft()!=None:
            q.append([node.getLeft(),temp+1])
        if node.getRight()!=None:
            q.append([node.getRight(),temp+1])
    return temp

b_tree_input=list(map(int,input().split()))

root=Node(b_tree_input[0])

for i in range(1,len(b_tree_input)):
    root.Insert_BTreeNode(b_tree_input[i])

print(root.height())
print(root.maxDepth())
```

For the sample input of 2,1,3,4.Both the function should return the answer as 3 but the height function returns the following.

> NameError: name 'height' is not defined

While the maxDepth() function returns the answer as 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `height`: I'm not a python programmer, but shouldn't it be

```
max(self.getLeft().height(), self.getRight().height())
// instead of
max(height(self.getLeft()), height(self.getRight()))
```

since `height` is a member function?

However, this implies you have to check `self.getLeft()` and `self.getRight()` for `None` values before calling `height`. If you don't want to do the extra checks, think of making `height` a global function unrelated to your class, then your previous approach on recursion should work.

The height function with checks for `None` could look as follows (no guarantee on the syntax details):

```
def height(self):
    if self is None:
        return 0
    elif self.left and self.right:
        return max(self.left.height(), self.right.height()) + 1
    elif self.left:
        return self.left.height() + 1
    elif self.right:
        return self.right.height() + 1
    else:
        return 1
```

In `maxDepth` you process child nodes in a right-to-left DFS but you only take the result of the last processed path instead of comparing current `temp` to the maximum of already found depths.

So in your `[2,1,3,4]` example, the execution order is as follows:

```
q=[[2,1]] -> take [2,1] ->  temp=1
q=[[1,2],[3,2]] -> take [3,2] ->  temp=2
q=[[1,2],[4,3]] -> take [4,3] ->  temp=3
q=[[1,2]] -> take [1,2] ->  temp=2
end
```

I think you can now figure out how to change your algorithm.

Also you should consider to change the `self is None` case to return `0`.

Comment: The height function would work correctly as i am passing the left pointer to the height function.

Comment: @DhruvMarwha well from your question it's hard to see which methods belong to your class definition, but see the following Q/A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349554/recursion-within-a-class

Comment: @DhruvMarwha so you changed it as I suggested and *the same error* appears? Now that I think about it, it might be related to `self.getRight()` or `getLeft()` returning `None`

Comment: I am getting the following error:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'height'. This should not come as in the preorder,postorder and inorder traversal,the syntax is the same.

Comment: @DhruvMarwha edited my answer. This new error is clearly related to the fact, that the member call syntax doesn't handle leaf nodes, where child nodes are `None`.

Comment: i tired the self.left.height() and self.right.height() but still my function does not work properly.Any tips?